# Docker output file and docker image during build (multistage build)

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I'm using multistage build to get output files from build phase. So my dockerfile is:

```
FROM ... AS build-stage
...

FROM scratch AS export-stage
COPY --from=build-stage /app/a.out /
```

And my 2 commands to build are:

```sh
DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1 docker build \
-t `cat Dockerfile.tag` \
-f Dockerfile \
--output type=local,dest=output_docker .
```

and

```sh
DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1 docker build \
-t `cat Dockerfile.tag` \
-f Dockerfile .
```

I'm ok, with output files, but I would like to get working docker image, so when I run command `docker run -it <docker_image_from_build> /bin/bash`, I'm getting following error:

```sh
docker: Error response from daemon: failed to create shim: OCI runtime create failed: 
container_linux.go:380: starting container process caused: exec: "/bin/bash": stat /bin/bash: 
no such file or directory: unknown.
ERRO[0000] error waiting for container: context canceled
```

As I understand second command to build image is outputing `export-stage`, which is almost empty image. How to bypass this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I think this should be ok: https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/#stop-at-a-specific-build-stage

So build command is getting argument, to build proper stage, in my case this is only build-stage.